# How to get all same properties from multiple classes?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, properties

**SITUATION**

I want to display all general properties of multiple classes. Lets say there is a class "A" with properties "a" and "c" ,  and there is a class "B" with properties "b" and "c" ... so i basically want to get the property "c"

Is there any easy way to do this?

**EDIT**

Sorry my bad that i didnt tell what i have programmed.

I basiclly have a list of classes and i want to get all properties that those classes have together.

My code is just a proof that i ve tried something.

real example : Visual Studio

If you select 2 buttons, then you will see all properties that those buttons have together

**CODE**

```
 private void GetAllProperties(ObservableCollection<DUIElement> selecteditems)
    {
        if (selecteditems == null)
            return;

        _properties.Clear();

        foreach (DUIElement item in selecteditems)
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.Name != nameof(DPropertyViewModel))
                    continue;

                foreach (DUIElement itemnext in selecteditems)
                {
                    if (item.GroupName == itemnext.GroupName)
                        continue;

                    foreach (PropertyInfo propertynext in itemnext.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                    {
                        if (propertynext.PropertyType.Name != nameof(DPropertyViewModel))
                            continue;

                        if (property.PropertyType.Name == propertynext.PropertyType.Name)
                        {
                            var prop = propertynext.GetValue(itemnext, null) as DPropertyViewModel;
                            _properties.Add(prop);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: I didn’t follow your code, because I don’t really know what you want to achieve exactly, but my Linq-Query should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to build a list of the properties that exist in all of the enumerated items:

```
List<string> Properties = null;

foreach (DUIElement item in selecteditems)
{
    // Check for first iteration
    if (Properties == null)
    {
        // Get name of properties from first iteration
        Properties = new List<string>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo item in item.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>())
            Properties.Add(item.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        // Check properties from current iteration
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            // Remove properties where they do not exist in current property list
            if (!Properties.Contains(property.Name))
                Properties.Remove(property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This effectively makes a copy of all properties in the first item, and then removes any properties that are not present in the remaining iterations.

The resulting property names will end up in `Properties`.

I am not sure whether you just need the property names, or whether you actually need the `PropertyInfo` for each of these.  However, you can simply use the `Properties` list to then match the `PropertyInfo` from the first object in `selecteditems`.

Comment: ty for your reply . Im gonna tryto do what u said later on , and if got solution for that, ill mark your answer as correct.